# Net-SNMP used in UNIX

Tags: unix, snmp, net-snmp

Does anyone know good tutorials online or books that will help with NET-SNMP.

Or can anybody recommend my a SNMP trap generator for Unix

Basically I want to send SNMP traps from UNIX to SCOM server  but i can not use SCOM AGENT as it is heavy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Net-SNMP includes a commandline tool "snmptrap" that you can use to send traps. Or you can use Perl to write script that does the trap sending.

The O'Reilly book "Essential SNMP" besides explaining SNMP in general, has many examples how to use SNMP from the command line or from Perl.

Comment: Thanks mate...Hmm i have that book but my biggest problem is to get Net-SNMP on my solaris first...I can use the snmptrap manual page but than if i type snmptrap it is not a recognised command

Comment: Strange. I have Solaris11 and snmptrap seems to be included in the minimum default installation. /usr/bin/snmptrap

Comment: is snmptrap a folder or a file. i see nothing like that in my usr/bin folder

Answer (score 0):

You can get tutorials from official **NET-SNMP wiki** - just search google.

Regarding your question, you can find one good article in this
[snmptrap tutorial link](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT%3asnmptrap)

If you're using UNIX/Solaris as your dev platform, make sure you include the "/usr/sfw/bin" folder in your **PATH** as it's not searched by default.